# Handle error caused from deserializing a null value

Tags: c#, json, error-handling

I have a Json file that can contain booleans with a null value. 
If I try to Deserialize these boolean I get a InvalidCastException because booleans are not nullable.

The line triggering the exception:

```
var result = serializer.Deserialize(jObject.GetValue(propertyName).CreateReader(), type);
```

How can I handle this so that I do not get an exception? catch the error and add it to a List, then continue the method. Instead of the application breaking, like it is now.

Comment: Does `null` mean something different from `false`? If so, you could define them as nullable `bool?`

Comment: @Freggar yes null means the customer did not enter any value, which is wrong. I would like to catch the exception and add it to a list

Comment: booleans are not nullable? Errmm .. are you sure? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/

Comment: @AdamBenson "Errmm" You cannot deserialize a null boolean. Which is all that matters here. You can set a Bool to null, if that is what you mean, but I'm not going to be toxic and link you to any basic documentation explaining the difference.

Comment: @Green_qaue - This is what makes SO such an unfriendly place. "Errrm" was meant to indicate uncertainty (as in I'm not sure I've understood you correctly, but does this help?) "I'm not going to be toxic" - that comes across as toxic. Just say nothing, or "thanks, maybe I didn't explain it well" or "I think you missed my point." Your original post said "booleans are not nullable" as though having a null bool in JSON is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new JsonSerializerSettings instance..

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                    {
                        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                    };
var jsonModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(jsonString, settings);
```

Comment: Where does this catch the exception? looks like it just ignores it?

Comment: Having nulls in fields are not an error from the JSON parsing perspective. It's an error according to your business rules. Just check if the field is null after the parsing. `if (customer.Property == null) { //exception or something other } `

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `JsonSerializerSettings` to handle the error. So that program does not throw exception. However in this case, the property will be set to default value if unable to convert/cast.

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                    {
                        Error = (sender, args) => { args.ErrorContext.Handled = true; }
                    };
var jsonModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(jsonString, settings);
```

You can read about this at [this](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationErrorHandling.htm) Newtonsoft doc link.